# Python WhatsApp: No module named yowsup

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, whatsapp, yowsup

I am keep getting this error despite of it's already installed. Check below:

```
MacBook:examples User$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from whatsapp import Client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/whatsapp.py", line 5, in <module>
    from yowsup import env
ImportError: No module named yowsup
>>> quit()
MacBook:examples User$ sudo pip install yowsup
Password:
The directory '/Users/User/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/User/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): yowsup in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: what happens if you try to import yowsup directly?

Comment: Same error is displayed

Comment: you should try using conda environments or virtualenv. It would make it easier to manage your packages and fix these sort of problems.

Comment: @riotburn Fine but why this issue is happening while all others packages are working. Do I need to restart system?